# function with appending not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, append

I'm trying to write a function to append things to a array of values then print them out but it returns __lldb_expr_444.taste when I print it out after calling my function?!
heres my code:

```
  // Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

struct taste {
var TheName = "blankName"

var TheDesc = "blankDesc"
}




var data = [taste]()


func addFruit(name:String,desc:String) {
data.append(taste(TheName: name as String, TheDesc: desc as String))


}

addFruit("cherry", "sweet")

println(data)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't name your vars starting it with uppercase letters

Answer (score 1):

You need to adopt the Printable protocol and implement the description computed variable that returns the textual struct representation.

```
struct taste: Printable {

  var TheName = "blankName"
  var TheDesc = "blankDesc"

  var description: String {
    return "TheName: \(TheName); TheDesc: \(TheDesc)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access data in the function but it has been declared outside from the function.

One way to solve this is to create a class with your array as class variable and the addFruit as function of the class.

Otherwise you could pass the array as parameter of the addFruit function to be able to modify it inside the function. In order to print your array, you can iterate on it.

```
var data:[taste]

func addFruit(name:String, desc:String, inout fruitArray:taste) {
    fruitArray.append(taste(TheName: name as String, TheDesc: desc as String))
}

addFruit("cherry", "sweet", &data)

for item in data{
    println(item)
}
```